# Using property OR in "conditions" parameter of askargs action with Semantic MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

I'm trying to fetch results via API using the module askargs. I have no problems getting results when I have just one condition or more conditions aggregated with the operator AND where I make use of the pipe character to separate them (like written in documentation).

E.g.

`[[Category:+]] AND [[Jurisdiction::A]] AND [[Type::B]]`

`Category:+ | Jurisdiction::A | Type::B`

But the pipe character doesn't work with OR.

I need to be able to use both logical conditions with several arguments within the same query.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

No. The API doesn't handle OR condition, due to simplistic code in the query parameters formatter.

See file [SemanticMediaWiki/src/MediaWiki/Api/ApiRequestParameterFormatter.php](https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/blob/cb928a5b475e0fe7943ddb7789eb3f6947ed8f0e/src/MediaWiki/Api/ApiRequestParameterFormatter.php)
 at line 132:

```
protected function formatConditions( $condition ) {
        return "[[$condition]]";  
    }
```

Every condition in the query is formatted with surrounding brackets, leading `OR` to be interpreted as a page title.

An alternative is to use `Special:Ask` with URL encoded query and json format:

```
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Ask/-5B-5BHas-20keyword::askargs-5D-5DOR-5B-5BHas-20keyword::ask-5D-5D/-3F%3Dhelp-20page/-3FHas-20description%3Ddescription/format%3Djson
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed it works, but only with two arguments. If I add a third argument, it doesn't return the expected results. (sorry if my question was not sufficiently clear about the number of arguments)

Comment: Well, changing the code is a bad idea from the beginning anyway (a nightmare for updates), so let simplify the answer to your question. No, the API doesn't provide what you need.

Comment: But the Special:Ask alternative should achieve the same result.

Comment: You are right, I already put a request for the development of this feature, we'll see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since I came here from a website search i'm going to add another neat possibility:

If you use the [Alternative separator](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main#main.2Fdatatypes) you can use a double pipe as logical OR conjunction.
Example:

```
%1FCategory:+%1FJurisdiction::A%1FType::B||C
```

Which should be read as following

```
Category:+ AND Jurisdiction::A AND (Type::B OR Type::C)
```